# bigchaindb set up and run cluster node error

Tags: mongodb, master-slave-replication

I have been following the instructions given on: https://docs.bigchaindb.com/projects/server/en/latest/production-nodes/setup-run-node.html in an attempt to create a cluster.

However I get this error when I try to add replicas:

> Quorum check failed because not enough voting nodes responded; required 2 but only the following 1 voting nodes responded: tom-Lenovo:27017; the following nodes did not respond affirmatively: tom-asus:27017 failed with Received heartbeat from member with the same member ID as ourself: 0

where I want `tom-Lenovo` to act as my primary and `tom-asus` to join as a secondary. I have a third laptop which should join as secondary so as to make a 3 member replica set. However I get the same error when I try to add it too.

The instruction page asks us to run mongodb and I use the following command to do so: `sudo mongod --replSet=bigchain-rs`. I have used this command on all 3 nodes.

I have also repeated the 'Configure BigchainDB Server' step on all 3 nodes.

I am running on Ubuntu 16.04.

I am new to bigchaindb and mongodb and all help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What manogodb version, you are using?

Comment: I am using version 3.4.9. I had installed the mongodb community edition for Ubuntu from https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that port 27017 is not open at your firewalls!

At command line tom-Lenovo, you give command `mongo tom-asus:27017` you should get answer. And same to the other direction!